# How to kill the process from its thread using c/cpp?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, process

Is there a way to kill the process from its thread? I have a process that starts a thread and the process waits for the input from the terminal. My requirement is to kill the process from the thread.

Scenario: the thread actually runs a timer to identify if the main process is idle (i.e no input given from the terminal) for certain intervals, then i want the thread to kill the process.

Comment: `exit();` should kill the process.

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has `std::thread` and C doesn't.  Please update your language tags as appropriate.

Comment: It really depends on the capabilities of the process.  If it has registered any [atexit/on_exit](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html) function and how those functions behave.

Comment: I would add that it is my recollection that on *nix systems, there's at least one signal you can send to a process that terminates the process without calling any atexit/on_exit` functions. Pretty sure there's a special termination function you can call from within the process, to bypass the signalling overhead. Hopefully, someone will chime in here with something more specific, or you'll find it in the course of your further research.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: preferably C++.

Comment: @Eljay: The process is waiting for input from the terminal. It wont terminate until manually killed. If you mean exit() at thread, it actually wont kill the process.

Comment: Depends on how polite an exit you want. Me, I'd reorder things so the task to be killed was in the thread and the live/die decision made in `main`. When `main` decides it's time to die, it sends a message to the thread asking it to wrap things up and return. When the thread ends, `main` returns. If the thread doesn't return in a reasonable amount of time, `main` takes whatever actions are necessary to exit the process and take the thread with it.

Comment: @user4581301: It's another way i.e. task to be killed is in main and the live/die decision is made in thread. When the thread decides to die it send message to main to terminate. nothing to wrap up by the main as it's idlely waiting.

Comment: @Dilip Either one will work. The main point is it's a lot easier to politely end a process from `main`.

Comment: Alarm(2) pretty much provides this functionality.   `alarm(5); p = getline(...); alarm(0);` will kill the program (and threads) if the user goes idle for 5s.  alarm(0) clears it.

Comment: @mevets: Do you mean implementing Alarm(2) in any thread of the process can kill the process and all other threads started by the process?

Comment: yes and I must type 15 chars....

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);`. It is included in windows.h.

Comment: The OP's question was not tagged for Windows, and the answer to the OP's question is more nuanced than just calling `exit`.